# Loop through NEW and OLD values into a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

In order to make a code as general as possible I am trying to find a way to loop through NEW and OLD variables (from a MySQL trigger) to get column name and value...

I would like to access the key (column name) and the value *NEW.columnName*.
Does anyone know a solution? 
Thank you!